# How to install PAM without packet manager

Tags: authentication, pam

I have an ARM based device with an embedded Linux installed on it. I need to install the PAM library on it and have it to handle authentication. I already have the cross-compiled version of PAM (1.5.1) and copied all the resulting files into the device. Which other steps I need to follow in order to properly install PAM on the target Linux and make them work? How to test them?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also have to build all the security and authentication related parts (libraries and application) to actually use PAM to make the whole thing work.

PAM doesn't automagically insert itself into the authentication process, just by being installed on the system. Applications must make active use of it. Identify which applications that are, build and package them to use your PAM build.

Comment: Thanks datenwolf. For example, say I would like to make "su" to use PAM in order to authenticate users. Can you please explain what kind of configuration should I need to do?
What do you mean for "build all the security and authentication related parts (libraries and application)" please?

Comment: @user15061000: PAM is not something that "magically" works just by installing it. When compiling programs like su, sudo or getty must be build-configured to actually use PAM. So if you want to use PAM you'll also have to install versions of all the programs you want to use PAM built with PAM support. This is more than just placing the right conf files in /etc – To be honest with you: I feel you're a little bit over your head here. PAM is security software and misconfiguring it has harsh implications. Look for a Linux distribution that fulfulls your requirements.